# System of equation AX=B

Tags: matrices

I need to find all solutions of the system of equations AX=B when $$A= \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
             1 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\
             3 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
             1 & -4 & -2 & 2 \\
                \end{array} } \right] \mbox{ and }  B= \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
             0 \\
             0 \\
             0 \\
                \end{array} } \right]$$

I reduced A by doing $R_2 \rightarrow 3R_1-R_2$ and $R_3 \rightarrow R_1-R_3$. But I get: $$ A'= \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
             1 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\
             0 & 6 & 3 & -1 \\
             0 & 6 & 3 & -1 \\
                \end{array} } \right]$$

Did I do something wrong ?

Comment: I guess it is   R3→R1−R3.

Comment: @jaseem You are right. I edited it

Comment: @user43418:You are doing great, just keep going, by eliminating row 3, dividing row two by 6 and then subtracting row 2 from row 1.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't do anything wrong. What it means is that you actually have only two equations instead of three.And you have four variables.This means that the solution has two parameters in it.

One way to proceed is by fixing two variables of your choice by by some parameters and solving for the rest of the variable.

For example, suppose the variables are (a,b,c,d)
From your reduced matrix,
$$6b+3c=d$$ 
Let $d=3k$
So that $a+2b+c+d=a+k+3k=0$
$a=-4k$
Now let $b=t$,this means $c=k-2t$
So the solution is (-4k,t,k-2t,3k) where t and k can take any real value. You can represent this as a linear combination of two base vectors.

Comment: So I get $X= \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
             \frac{5}{3} \mu \\
             \frac{1}{6} \mu - \frac{1}{2} \lambda\\
             \lambda\\
             \mu \\
                \end{array} } \right]$ such that $(\lambda, \mu) \in \mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: @user43418 I have edited the answer to include a possible solution,
It's $\frac{-4\mu}{3}$ instead of $5/3 \mu$